# Proof that $\lfloor x + x\sqrt3 \rfloor = x + \lfloor x\sqrt3 \rfloor$ Where $x \in N$

Tags: induction, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm not sure if this is true or not. I was going to prove it via induction. Here is what I have so far.

Base Case (x=0): $\lfloor 0 + 0\rfloor = 0 = 0 + \lfloor 0 \rfloor$

Induction Hypothesis (IH): $\lfloor x + x\sqrt3\rfloor = x + \lfloor x\sqrt3 \rfloor$

Induction Step: $\lfloor x + 1 + (x + 1)\sqrt3\rfloor = \lfloor x + (x + 1)\sqrt3\rfloor + 1$.

This is where I get stuck. Any help? I'm not convinced that this is even true, but I can't think of a counter example.

Comment: the definition of $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$ is $f(n+\epsilon) = n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}, \epsilon \in [0;1[$ so $f(n+x) = n+f(x)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (this is what you need to prove, for example by induction)

Comment: Since $x\in\Bbb N$, this question makes a good proof: [Number Theory Question on the floor function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348644/number-theory-question-on-the-floor-function)

Answer (score 1):

We don't need induction. Note $\lfloor n + u \rfloor = \lfloor u \rfloor + n$ for natural $n$. This follows since $\lfloor u \rfloor = u - \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \in [0,1)$.

So we get

$\lfloor n + u \rfloor = \lfloor n + \epsilon + \lfloor u \rfloor \rfloor$ = $n + \lfloor u \rfloor$ since $\lfloor u \rfloor + n  ≤ n + \epsilon + \lfloor u \rfloor < \lfloor u \rfloor + n + 1 $

Answer (score 1):

Write $x\sqrt 3=m+\epsilon $ where $m\in \mathbb N$ and $0<\epsilon <1$.

Then, on one hand, we have

$\lfloor x+x\sqrt 3\rfloor =\lfloor (x+m)+\epsilon \rfloor=x+m$

and on the other

$x+\lfloor x\sqrt 3\rfloor =x+\lfloor m+\epsilon \rfloor =x+m$

so the two sides are equal.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.

Comment: Kind of nasty to downvote my answer isn't it? JUust because didn't read your answer. But now that I did, I found an error, so I wll downvote you also.

Comment: *sigh*. At least I gave you the reason I downvoted you

Comment: you wrote this: $\lfloor u \rfloor = u - \epsilon$ and it's not right. You really should watch the downvoting. Like I said II did not read your answer. Downvotes should be for bad proofs not for bruised egos.

Comment: Fine, I apologize. But remember the feature is not a personal insult. Can you kindly explain how that it is an error? Suppose we take $u=6.4$. Then the floor is $6$ and $\epsilon$ is 0.4.

Comment: Note also that I would upvote you but it does not let me unless you edit it again, for some reason.

Comment: $\lfloor 6.4\rfloor = \lfloor 6+.4\rfloor =6$ with $\epsilon =.4$. I don't care about the downvote. But it should be used only if the proof is not right and then only sparingly. The idea is to help the OP, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35423/discussion-between-mathematicsstudent1122-and-chilango).